# Resetting RecyclerView cached view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have implemented `setSelected` in `RecyclerView.onBindViewHolder` and it select the row tapped by the user. If the user select another row then the previous row also get deselected. The issue is when I scroll the view a bit down so that the previously selected row get hidden, then I select new row and then scroll up, the old row is retrieved from cache with its view selected.

Is there any way to handle cached view so I can deselect the old row on its appearance?

Following is my code to reset the previous row upon user tap. I am using `selectedPos` to save selected row pos:

```
void row_click(View view) {
            view.setSelected(true);
            RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) view.getParent();

            // reset previous selection
            if (selectedPos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                View previousView = rv.getChildAt(selectedPos);
                if (previousView != null) {
                    ((RecordingsViewHolder) rv.getChildViewHolder(previousView)).equalizer.hide();
                    previousView.setSelected(false);
                }
            }

            selectedPos = rv.getChildLayoutPosition(view);
            playlist.setValue((com.alhuda.al_huda_live.common.viewmodel.Playlist) view.getTag());
        }
```

In `onBindViewHolder` I am using this code to select/deselect the row:

```
holder.itemView.setSelected(selectedPos == position);
```

Comment: try `notifyItemChanged(selectedPos);`

Comment: @Eminem where to use this code.. .In click item?

Comment: yes try it,you have to notify the changed item

Comment: @Eminem yes it works. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
notifyItemChanged(selectedPos);
```

Notify any registered observers that the item at position has changed with an optional payload object.

This is an item change event, not a structural change event. It indicates that any reflection of the data at position is out of date and should be updated. The item at position retains the same identity.[(1)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int,%20java.lang.Object))